# c++, playing a WAV file from Windows 7 Service

Tags: c++, service, windows-7, wav

I have a C++ application that plays a WAV file when some conditions are meet. It works fine when running as a console, but it does not work when running as a service. I am using the PlaySound function, I tried with many flag combinations. The PlaySound functions always returns TRUE, even when called from the service. it also worked fine when running on Windows XP as a service.
It looks like one of those security limitation from Windows 7. Is this true? Is there a way that I can play a WAV file from Windows 7 Service in C++?

Thanks!!
John

Comment: have you checked your session? sound is usually session specific, if you're not in the user session then it won't sound.

Comment: Thanks Mgetz for the reply. Can a Windows Service have a user session? If yes, how do I set it up?

Comment: I couldn't say (as I don't know) but [there is a good guide](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx) as to what you're up against

Comment: Thanks Mgetz, the link you posted help me understand the issue. And also that there is not much I can do, this is a security restriction from Windows 7 OS. Thanks!